# Let $T:V\to W$ be linear, show $\ker T$ is a subspace of $V$ and $\operatorname{im} T = T(V)$ is a subspace of $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

OK, so I have already proven that $\ker T$ is a subspace of $V$, which is pretty obvious because the kernel is just the $0$'s, though I'm not sure I did it formally enough. The second part I don't know how to do, it's not clear to me why it is a subspace of $W$ rather than of $V$.

The material I know is first semester algebra.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel is just $\bf 0$ if and only if $T$ is injective, so you'll have to fix that. Basically, you want to:

1. Given ${\bf u},{\bf v}\in \ker T$, $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, prove that
   ${\bf u}+\alpha{\bf v} \in \ker T$. To show this, compute $T({\bf
       u}+\alpha{\bf v})$, and see what happens.
2. We have that $T(V)$ is a subspace of $W$ and not of $V$, because
   firstly, it is a subset of $W$, not of $V$. Given $\bar{{\bf
       u}},\bar{\bf v} \in T(V)$, $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, prove that ${\bf
       u}+\alpha{\bf v} \in T(V)$. You know that exists ${\bf u},{\bf v}
       \in V$ such that $T{\bf u}=\bar{\bf u}$ and $T{\bf v}=\bar{\bf v}$.
   What element in $V$ would have $\bar{\bf u}+\alpha\bar{\bf v}$ as
   image?

Comment: the element would be u+αv

Comment: That's right. To formalize it, do a quick computation to show that $T({\bf u}+\alpha{\bf v}) = \bar{\bf u}+\alpha\bar{\bf v}$.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't mind it, glad to help.